# Calling anonymous functions defined as object variables in php

Tags: php, class, anonymous-function

I have php code like:

```
class Foo {
  public $anonFunction;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->anonFunction = function() {
      echo "called";
    }
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();
//First method
$bar = $foo->anonFunction();
$bar();
//Second method
call_user_func($foo->anonFunction);
//Third method that doesn't work
$foo->anonFunction();
```

Is there a way in php that I can use the third method to call anonymous functions defined as class properties?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not directly. `$foo->anonFunction();` does not work because PHP will try to call the method on that object directly. It will not check if there is a property of the name storing a callable. You can intercept the method call though.

Add this to the class definition

```
  public function __call($method, $args) {
     if(isset($this->$method) && is_callable($this->$method)) {
         return call_user_func_array(
             $this->$method, 
             $args
         );
     }
  }
```

This technique is also explained in

- [JavaScript-style object literals](http://www.phpied.com/javascript-style-object-literals-in-php/)

Comment: thanks, at least now I know that it's not possible but it's possible via a workaround.