# method overriding for single instance v2

Tags: php, oop, overriding

Is it possible to override a method for a single instance? e.g.

```
class test
{
    protected function print()
    {
    echo "printed from old method";
    }
}

$a= new test();
can i overrride method "print" only for object $a?
e.g. $a->test=function(){echo "printed with new method";}
```

I know its abit weird but in my project a common class ("base") is part of many other classes each of which needs a slightly modified version of "base". I just need to override one method each time. Trying to avoid creating a huge number of subclasses of "base" for this purpose.

p.s. i have seen the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998807/php-override-function-of-a-single-instance) you propose but it doesn't work for me.
php version is 7.4.3

here is my code:

```
class nodeGroup
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo "internal";
    }
        
}

$a= new nodeGroup();
$a->test = (function() {
    echo "external";
})->bindTo($a);

$a->test();

result is "internal"
```

Comment: Doesn't this go against OCP?

Comment: Have you considered using interfaces?

Comment: I think the right way to do this is to either make a new class that inherits from the original class and overrides the method, or use interfaces.  Another option would be to add a member that is a pointer to the function you want to call and call it in the method if it is not false, otherwise, use the normal method function.  I think this violates the policy of least surprise though, and trying to override a method on an instanced object most certainly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare an [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) on the fly:

```
$a = new class extends nodeGroup {
    public function test()
    {
        echo 'external';
    }
};

$a->test();  // 'external'
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/puNOB)**

Comment: This could be the solution but the actual class has many other methods and properties that don't change and would need to be declared again in the anonymous class.

Comment: @ParakmiI No they wouldn't: this anonymous class extends `nodeGroup`, therefore it inherits everything from it (except what you override explicitly). Edited the demo link with a corresponding example.

Comment: I didn't know you can do that. Seems like a very good solution. Thank you.

Comment: @ParakmiI It's available since PHP 7. Not the most common feature around, but it's got its uses.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property to the class, and the `print()` method can check whether the property is set.

```
class test
{
    public $print_function;

    public function print()
    {
        if (isset($this->$print_function)) {
            ($this->$print_function)();
        } else {
            echo "printed from old method";
        }
    }
}

$a = new test();
$a->print_function = function() {
    echo "printed with new method";
};
$a->print();
```

Comment: This works good Thanks.
However it would be usefull to know if there is a cleaner way to averride methods in an instance. Afraid there isn't....

Comment: The "clean" way to do it would be to define a subclass and use that.