# add method/function in instance of stdClass in instance context for using $this in PHP?

Tags: php, function, closures, stdclass, php-8

How add function to instance object of stdClass?

```
$obj = (object)['name' => 'test', 'x' => 0];
$obj->move = function() { $this->x++; return $this->x; };
var_dump(($obj->move)());
```

I try use closure to simulate method, there is another way to directly add dynamicly a function to my object?

For my exemple, there is an error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

so how keep object context, for use `$this` in my closure ?

I try add `use($obj)` but error stay... (normal)

So how can I do ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868066/dynamically-create-php-class-functions for how to create a method in the class dynamically.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't create a class?

Comment: @ManuelGuzman yes, I put it in my exemple. My data is an array at the begining, and there is a cast to `object` (I can't change this in real case)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701638/how-to-bind-this-to-a-php-function

Comment: @gre_gor how you use this in my exemple? I need use `$obj->move` not `Closure::bind(...)` each time I want invoke my mathod

Comment: `$obj->move = Closure::fromCallable(function() { $this->x++; return $this->x; })->bindTo($obj);`

Comment: @gre_gor nice ! it's that :) can you add an anwser ? I valid it ;)

Comment: Since it's closed I can't. Maybe the dupe target should just be changed.

Comment: Also `fromCallable` is unnecessary. You can just do `$obj->move = (function() { $this->x++; return $this->x; })->bindTo($obj);`

Comment: I find this, it's exacly what you said, thx :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998807/php-override-function-of-a-single-instance

Comment: @gre_gor I make this global function `function addMethodToObject($obj, $func_name, $func)
{
  $obj->{$func_name} = $func->bindTo($obj);
}`, but how an I override stdClass for direcly do `$obj->addMethod('move', function(){...})` instead ?

Comment: Just add it to the object the same way?